Pod getting stuck in ContainerCreating state when it is attached to 2 EFS RWX volume
Created EFS file system on aws console
Using EFS file system ID from step 1 we created storage class and used that storage class in app deployment
After helm deployment we got EFS access point, pv and pvc created however the pod which has 2 RWX volumes failing to mount the persistent volume and getting stuck in containerCreating state.
If we remove one RWX volume, the pod is coming up fine. Is there any issue with 2 RWX volumes in same eks pod.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mre]?  Remember that Stack Overflow questions need to specifically be about programming; it may be more appropriate to ask deployment-oriented questions on another site like [devops.se] or [sf].

Thanks David, I understand, i have posted my question with thorough details on DevOps portal, and will remove it from here now https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/eks-pod-stuck-in-containercreating-state-when-attached-to-2-claims-with-rwx-acc

here is the link to my same question on DevOps stackexchange portal
